# Swift: background color is changed when presenting view controller modally

Tags: ios, swift

I'm presenting a `MFMessageComposeViewController` modally from a view controller. The parent controller has black background and light status bar style. When `MFMessageComposeViewController` is presented, the parent controller background and status bar style change.

The first image shows the top area of the parent controller before presenting `MFMessageComposeViewController`. The second shows the top area of parent controller when `MFMessageComposeViewController` is presented. I tried changing multiple settings, eg. tint color and background color for the navigation controller holding the parent controller but none works. My knowledge is very basic so chances are I'm misunderstanding very basic Swift concepts.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have set your `UIWindow` background colour to white. Try making it transparent in `AppDelegate` before `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` or remove it completely:

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Had the same issue, this solution fixed it for me (I initially had `window.backgroundColor = .white` )